# How to lose focus on a cell in SlickGrid

Tags: jquery-autocomplete, slickgrid

My question is exactly opposite of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842946/select-focus-cell-using-slickgrid). So what I'm trying is I'm trying to find a way to lose focus on a cell after user selects an item from the autocomplete combobox in that cell.

```
 $input.autocomplete({
                delay: 0,
                minLength: 0, 
                source: args.column.options,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $input.val(ui.item.label);
                   grid.getEditController().commitCurrentEdit();
              return false;
                }
            });
```

I used this code to lose focus indirectly after finishing with editing. It works fine, however, the cell stays selected somehow.

```
grid.getEditController().commitCurrentEdit();
```

I also tried the code below to lose focus but it throws error everytime when I run the code.

```
grid.setActiveCell();
grid.setSelectedRows(-1);
```

After selecting an item from the autocomplete combobox, I want the grid to lose focus and select nothing on the viewport of the grid.

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: Have you tried simply adding `.blur()` to the end of your `$input.val(ui.item.label)` statement in your select function.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `grid.resetActiveCell()`.

Comment: And instead of grid.setSelectedRows(-1); one should use:
grid.setSelectedRows({});

Answer (score 0):

There was a commit made to the master branch last week that might address your issue: [Fix keyboard focus getting trapped when cell has tabbable elements.](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/commit/86ce1e1c9d42ba5e10f8f335876e9a8ad03a5f2c)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it as follows,

```
            if (grid.getActiveCell()) {
            var row = grid.getActiveCell().row;
            var cell = grid.getActiveCell().cell;
            grid.gotoCell(row, cell, false);
        }
```